# How to stop broadcasting WAN network group to LAN network group?

Tags: ipv4, network, ip-address

First, I'm not really good at networking terminologies, So I'll explain the case as simple as possible.

I have a PFSense set up, my PFsense gets its internet through its WAN IP 192.168.10.2
and disperse to clients on its DHCP LAN IPS 192.168.20.100~150

Everything works, 20.xx has internet access, problem is they also can ping the ip groups in 10.x example PC outside pfsense with IP 192.168.10.50

How do I stop this from happening? This also applies to routers.

Comment: "_How to stop broadcasting WAN network group to LAN network group?_" Broadcasts do not cross routers. In the question body, there is no mention of broadcast, only ping, which is something completely different. Ping uses ICMP, and you can block it with an ACL. Please edit your question to include the [sanitized] router configuration.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a firewall rule permitting "LAN" clients' requests to *any* destination address to be forwarded out of the "WAN" interface, the pfSense does just that.

If you want to restrict that rule in part, you need to put another rule in front, explicitly denying access to the "WAN" subnet itself.

Broadcasts don't cross routers generally, so that doesn't seem to be your problem.